# Saving nested form parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Nested form params aren't saving to the ShopProductPrintFile database model.

The following params pass:

```
..., "print_locations"=>{"1"=>{"shop_product_print_files_attributes"=>{"print_file"=>"a", "print_location_id"=>"1"}}, "2"=>{"shop_product_print_files_attributes"=>{"print_file"=>"", "print_location_id"=>"2"}}, "3"=>{"shop_product_print_files_attributes"=>{"print_file"=>"a", "print_location_id"=>"3"}}, "4"=>{"shop_product_print_files_attributes"=>{"print_file"=>"", "print_location_id"=>"4"}}, "5"=>{"shop_product_print_files_attributes"=>{"print_file"=>"", "print_location_id"=>"5"}}, "6"=>{"shop_product_print_files_attributes"=>{"print_file"=>"", "print_location_id"=>"6"}}},...
```

Form:

```
...
<% PrintLocation.all.each do |pl| %>
   <%= f.fields_for 'print_locations[]', pl do |ff| %>
      <%= ff.fields_for :shop_product_print_files_attributes do |fff|  %>
      <%= fff.text_field :print_file %>
      <%= fff.hidden_field :print_location_id, value: pl.id %>
      <% end %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
...
```

**Models:**

```
class ShopProduct < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :shop_product_print_files
  has_many :print_locations, through: :shop_product_print_files
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shop_product_print_files

end

class ShopProductPrintFile < ApplicationRecord

  belongs_to :shop_product
  belongs_to :print_location
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :print_location

end

class PrintLocation < ApplicationRecord

  has_many :shop_product_print_files
  has_many :shop_products, through: :shop_product_print_files
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :shop_product_print_files

end
```

**params:**

```
def shop_product_params
    params.require(:shop_product).permit(:product_id, :store_product_id, :shop_id, :store_variant_id, :sync, :print_file_location, shop_product_print_files_attributes: [ :id, :print_file, :print_location_id, :shop_product_id ] )
end
```

I am under the impression these should be saving as long as the strong_params are done correctly, which i believe they are? or...?

When creating a ShopProduct, there are 6 designated PrintLocation's set in the PrintLocation (id, name) model with the ability to save a `print_file` per PrintLocation.  Then the ShopProductPrintFile model will house the `shop_product_id`, `print_location_id`, and `print_file`.

Entire console after params from shown above:

```
2019-06-16T04:08:05.734012+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-06-16T04:08:05.733918 #4]  INFO -- : [..] Started PATCH "/shop_products/42" for 69.118.200.110 at 2019-06-16 04:08:05 +0000

2019-06-16T04:08:05.736086+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-06-16T04:08:05.736010 #4]  INFO -- : [..] Processing by ShopProductsController#update as HTML

2019-06-16T04:08:05.736353+00:00 app[web.1]: I, [2019-06-16T04:08:05.736280 #4]  INFO -- : [..]   Parameters: {....., "print_locations"=>{"1"=>{"shop_product_print_files_attributes"=>{"print_file"=>"a", "print_location_id"=>"1"}}, "2"=>{"shop_product_print_files_attributes"=>{"print_file"=>"a", "print_location_id"=>"2"}}, "3"=>{"shop_product_print_files_attributes"=>{"print_file"=>"b", "print_location_id"=>"3"}}, "4"=>{"shop_product_print_files_attributes"=>{"print_file"=>"", "print_location_id"=>"4"}}, "5"=>{"shop_product_print_files_attributes"=>{"print_file"=>"", "print_location_id"=>"5"}}, "6"=>{"shop_product_print_files_attributes"=>{"print_file"=>"", "print_location_id"=>"6"}}}, ......}

2019-06-16T04:08:05.741476+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-06-16T04:08:05.741391 #4] DEBUG -- : [..]   [1m[36mCart Load (2.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "carts".* FROM "carts" WHERE "carts"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 20], ["LIMIT", 1]]

2019-06-16T04:08:05.745383+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-06-16T04:08:05.745304 #4] DEBUG -- : [..]   [1m[36mUser Load (3.0ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]

2019-06-16T04:08:05.751234+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-06-16T04:08:05.750661 #4] DEBUG -- : [..]   [1m[36mShopProduct Load (1.5ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "shop_products".* FROM "shop_products" WHERE "shop_products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 42], ["LIMIT", 1]]

2019-06-16T04:08:05.756181+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-06-16T04:08:05.756091 #4] DEBUG -- : [..]   [1m[36mShopProduct Load (0.9ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "shop_products".* FROM "shop_products" WHERE "shop_products"."store_variant_id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["store_variant_id", 15345629364273], ["LIMIT", 1]]

2019-06-16T04:08:05.759914+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-06-16T04:08:05.759748 #4] DEBUG -- : [a1974bea-579d-42fe-b8aa-66a99314431e]   [1m[36mProduct Load (0.9ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "products".* FROM "products" WHERE "products"."id" = $1 LIMIT $2[0m  [["id", 3], ["LIMIT", 1]]

2019-06-16T04:08:05.762239+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-06-16T04:08:05.762155 #4] DEBUG -- : [..]   [1m[35m (0.7ms)[0m  [1m[35mBEGIN[0m

2019-06-16T04:08:05.766104+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-06-16T04:08:05.766013 #4] DEBUG -- : [a1974bea-579d-42fe-b8aa-66a99314431e]   [1m[36mShopProduct Exists (0.9ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  1 AS one FROM "shop_products" WHERE "shop_products"."store_variant_id" = $1 AND "shop_products"."id" != $2 LIMIT $3[0m  [["store_variant_id", 15345629364273], ["id", 42], ["LIMIT", 1]]

2019-06-16T04:08:05.768566+00:00 app[web.1]: D, [2019-06-16T04:08:05.768495 #4] DEBUG -- : [a1974bea-579d-42fe-b8aa-66a99314431e]   [1m[35m (0.8ms)[0m  [1m[35mCOMMIT[0m
```

Comment: What does your server console show?

Comment: @jvillian updated the post at the bottom to include it all..  The update, new , and create have no build methods.  from what I have been told, I don't need one.  But when i use one, i receive validation errors anyway --- even when the information is passed.

Comment: Is that wat you were looking 4?